# Parity-like Solution for using Ledger Nano Anywhere

Tags: parity, metamask, ledger-nano-s

I'm looking for a "Parity-like" solution so that I'm able to use my Ledger Nano on any Ethereum-powered website that doesn't support a Nano natively (something like Radar Relay).

I know I can do this with Parity, BUT, I also need it check a few more boxes:

1) I need to be able to use it anywhere... not just on the host that's running Parity (I know about Parity public nodes and how to tunnel SSH, these options don't support the Nano).

2) Prefer not to have to do any syncing at all - would like to be able to do "light"

It seems that if MetaMask supported Ledger Nanos, it would be exactly what I'm looking for. Something I can login to on any computer, connect my Nano and start signing transactions from the Nano on sites that don't explicitly support the Nano.

Hoping there's something out there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything like this available, so I decided to write something myself. I've just released the first beta version of [SpaceSuit](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spacesuit/ogonghphdgcdealjfknchhgiaabendkl), a Chrome plugin that enables Ledger wallet users to use Dapps - like MetaMask, but for hardware wallets.

It's very much beta quality at this stage, but feel free to try it out, and [raise any bugs you find](https://github.com/jamespic/SpaceSuit/issues).

Answer (score 0):

Metamask has [recently added support](https://medium.com/metamask/metamask-now-supports-ledger-hardware-wallets-847f4d51546) for the Ledger and Trezor hardware wallets, and you can now use your hardware wallet with any dapp that supports the standard Web3 provider interface.